# Spring JPA result query with right number of rows but with empty fields

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I´m new with Spring and JPA, and I´m trying to get a list of elements with JPA query, but what i´m getting is a list with the right number of rows (the same query on sqldeveloper returns the same number of rows) but with all fields with null value.

Here is my code for Entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MTINPTEPK.class)
@Table(name = "MTIN_PTE")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(resultClass=MTINPTE.class,name = "MTINPTE.findByFechas", query=
            "SELECT "
            + "' ' AS CAMPO1, EEXIDE, ' ' AS CAMPO2, ' ' AS CAMPO3, ' ' AS CAMPO4, EEXNAC,
...

public class MTINPTE {


    @Column(name="CAMPO1") 
    private String campo1;
    @Id
    @Column(name="EEXIDE")
    private String eexide;

    @Column(name="CAMPO2")
    private String campo2;

    @Column(name="CAMPO3")
    private String campo3;

    @Column(name="CAMPO4")
    private String campo4;
    @Id
    @Column(name="EEXNAC")
    private String eexnac;
```

The PK

```
 public class MTINPTEPK implements Serializable{

        private String campo1;
        private String eexide;
        private String campo2;
        private String campo3;
        private String campo4;
        private String eexnac;
...
```

The repo

```
public interface MTINPTERepository extends CrudRepository<MTINPTE, MTINPTEPK> 
{
    @Query
    public List<MTINPTE> findByFechas(Date fechaDesde, Date fechaHasta);    

}
```

And the service

```
List<MTINPTE> listaMTINPTE = mtinPteRepository.findByFechas(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
```

Well, when I try to execute findByFechas I get the right number of rows on listaMTINPTE.size(), but the fields of each element are null.

Can you give me a hand?

Thanks!!.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the problem, it seems that when any field from query returns null, then the whole item get a null value. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You're executing your NamedNativeQuery. In this you return all columns empty ( ' ' as columname).

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(resultClass=MTINPTE.class,name = "MTINPTE.findByFechas", query=
            "SELECT "
            + "' ' AS CAMPO1, EEXIDE, ' ' AS CAMPO2, ' ' AS CAMPO3, ' ' AS CAMPO4, EEXNAC,
```

Your code isn't complete (tablename in this query is missing).

Just remove the NamedNativeQuery and create a clean mapping of your Database table.

Comment: I didn't post the full query (its really large), and I can't map the table cause my query is for several tables, not just one. Ignore the field that has the ' '. They has to be like this. I don't think thats the problem. The field eexdie and eexnac are normal and it doesnt work either.